# SQL stored procedure different execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

Well, I have a stored procedure on SQL server 2012. When I execute it with the same parameters from SSMS it always takes different time to get results.I have observed that I need from 10sec to 10mins to wait. What could be a reason? Where is to start digging? I can not post the code here because it's too large, but I think some common recommendations might appear.

Comment: Is your procedure always the only thing SQL Server is doing or could it sometimes also be hard at work on other things too?

Comment: @hatchet nope, I am the only one user who is working and server is not busy with other actions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the time difference between runs is rather large, so it could be that the system may be under load when you run this queries. Is this in a production environment?
To troubleshoot:
Turn on Actual Query Plan and execute the query/
Check that other queries are not blocking your query (sp_who2)
You can also run SQL Profiler when you run your query.